# Java- Idea behind Swing Serialization

Tags: java, swing

Am not able to find the rational behind swing components implementing Serializable interface. Example : javax.swing.JComponent - the base class itself

Comment: You can't find any because there is none :) the links above should explain _why_ they decided to make `JComponent` serializable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html

> The current serialization support is appropriate for short term
>   storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing.
>   As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been
>   added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder.

You must remind that Serialization is used for represent an object as a sequence of bits, later you can send this through network or save their state in disk, so this is necessary in certain scenarios like RMI.